# ReactJS, Router, Redux: How to use HTML <a/> as <Link/>?

Tags: javascript, html, react-router, reactjs

Is there a way to get the HTML `<a href=""> Home </a>` to work like that of

```
<Link to={`Home`} style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>
    Home
</Link>
```

?

I tried nesting the `<a/>` inside the Link and got the following error: `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>. See NavBar > Link > a > ... > a.`

**EDIT - Code Snippet**

```
<Link to={`Home`} style={{textDecoration:'none'}}>
    <a href="">Home</a>
</Link>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? <a> pretty much is <Link>.

Comment: @QuietBits Styling for <a> is implemented differently. For example, if I replace <a> with <Link>, it is positioned differently as well.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet and screenshot of what you see in the DOM when you inspect those links?

Comment: @QuietBits Updated the original post with code snippet. And ask for the screenshot, could you clarify on inspecting the links?

Comment: Your code snipped is wrong. You can't have <a> nested inside the <Link>, they are the same thing. Please read the React Router docs, they have very good examples and guide lines: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router

Comment: Not sure if the other comments above answered your question, but it seems that you've missed the fact that `<Link>` does in the DOM render as an `<a>` the difference is basically only behavioral (aside from some attributes that play no role in the layout). I'm not sure if `<Link>` accepts the `style` attribute or not, but you're better off applying a css style like so: `a {text-decoration: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

A Link component is rendered to the DOM as a  tag, so the css targeting a generic  should apply to Link, too. You can also give the link a custom className for correct styling.

It is surely wrong to have an  tag inside a  because that would nest two anchor tags in the DOM which is not valid HTML5, which triggers the React error you get.